# Command Pattern with responsible commands

Tags: c#, design-patterns, command

Well, I'm trying to implement command pattern to create interaction with an object.

Almost all of commands that would be created consist of request to an object and response from that object.

So the question is - how to manage this responses?

It's easy to make, when all commands - void. No matter what they are, you can execute them if they implements @executable@ interface, so have

void Execute(object params)

But what to do, when their responses have different types? Maybe the command pattern is not right for this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ICommandResponse Execute(object params)
```

You can return an interface with a ResponseType property that gives you information about the concrete response type.

Comment: So for example, i make like this

class StringResponce : ICommandResponce
{
    Type ResponceType{ get {return typeof(String);}}
    .....
}

Answer (score 0):

Make use of .NET's built-in command pattern types and lambdas.

First all all, you do not need your own command patetrn interface. Use `Action<T>`. So, for example, any command called must be of the following signature:

```
void Command(object params)
```

Then, for any command that isn't of this form, provide a lambda shim for it, eg:

```
() => { SomeCommandThatTakesTwoParamsAndRetrunsInt(parms.part1, params.part2); }
```

The above lambda then complies with the `void Command(object params)` requirements.

Comment: @Virviil That's what the lambdas are for, they are wrappers over your commands that aren't void.

Answer (score 0):

Command execution result may be event.

Example:

```
class ChangeNameCommand
{
    int _id;
    string _name;
    IRepository _repository;
    IEventPublisher _publisher;

    public ChangeNameCommand(int id, string name, IRepository repository, IEventPublisher publisher)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _repository = repository;
        _publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        User user = _repository.Get(_id)
        user.Name = _name;
        _repository.Save(user);

        NameChangedEvent e = new NameChangedEvent();
        _publisher.Publish(e);
    }
}

class UserNameChanged : IHandler<NameChangedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(NameChangedEvent e)
    {
        //TODO...
    }
}
```